dkms error due to kernel headers mismatch
Newbie here.
I am trying to install a device driver and it does ‘dkms’ in the background.
I have Ubuntu 22.04.5 that has kernel 6.*
When dkms is run, I get compilation errors as the api’s called from device driver source files don’t match Linux headers.
The same driver gets installed on Ubuntu 18 that has kernel 5.*
Can I somehow fix this issue on Ubuntu 22 by installing 5.* headers and forcing dkms to take that ?

The dkms builds the executable for api so that it will install into the currently installed (or potential) kernel so the headers have to match the currently installed (or potential) kernel. Normally, if the headers are changed then a new version of the api sources are needed. Find out what you are building and see if a compatible source tree is available for it.  ('dkms status' will show the target, the kernel. the architecture and whether it is installed. run it and append the results to your question.)
